# closure over each object of class

Tags: grails, closures

i am trying to call a closure over each object of a class, and then displaying the objects which returned by the closure. 
the closure is:

```
    def activitiesPlanned={
        cal.set(this.plannedStartDate)
        def planDateMonth=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        def planDateYear=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    }
```

the call i made is:

```
 def getActivitiesPlanned(int month,int year){
       countActivitiesPlanned=ProgressData.each{it.activitiesPlanned.findAllWhere(planDateMonth:month,planDateYear:year).count()}
    println countActivitiesPlanned
}
```

Domain Class  //EDIT

```
package main
class ProgressData {
//String milestoneName
String taskId   //Added later
String taskDescription
String taskCategory
Integer plannedHours  
Integer actualHours      
Date plannedStartDate     
Date actualStartDate     
Date plannedEndDate     
Date actualEndDate     
Integer stepsCreated=0    
Integer stepsExecuted=0   
String status   //Originally Completed
String assignedTo
//String unplanned
String accepted //Added later
def ProgressData(){}

static constraints = {
   //milestoneName(blank:false)
   taskDescription(blank:false)
   taskCategory(blank:false)
   plannedHours(blank:false)
   actualHours(blank:false)
   id generator:"assigned",name:"taskId"
}

 Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance()
 def activitiesPlanned={
        cal.set(this.plannedStartDate)
        def planDateMonth=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        def planDateYear=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    }
static hasMany=[defects:DefectData]
```

}

I am getting: "No such property: activitiesPlanned for class: main.ProgressData Possible solutions: activitiesPlanned". what issue may be there?

Comment: Is Progressdata your domain class? May be you could post a full code example.

Comment: yes. ProgressData is my domain class. i'll post the domain class code

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want .each{} rather .sum{}

Example:

```
def listThing = [1,2,3]
def sumOfList = listThing.sum{it}
assert sumOfList == 6
```

Also ProgressData is a Domain Class so you can't use `.each{}` on it.  You have to do `ProgressData.list().each{` and by that I really mean `ProgressData.list().sum{` for what I think you're trying to do.

Also, that activitiesPlanned closure doesn't return any activities...